# No Network connection

Tags: networking, drivers

I have just installed a new Asus 9750 motherboard and installed Ubuntu 15.04. My network says 'ethernet not managed'. I have set the ip address etc., and also added to /etc/network/etc.

Windows 7 on the same motherboard has no problem. So, at the moment I have had to revert to Microsoft for anything needing an internet connection.

Comment: have you installed the necessary drivers for wifi etc.?

Comment: yes because Windows 7 works -so the motherboard drivers are there..I am using a wired connectoin.

Comment: The network controller is a 'Realtec PCIe GBe Family controller' according to Windows7.

Comment: doen't matter if the drivers are there in windows, it will not work if they are not in Ubuntu. what's the output of `lspci` and `lshw -c network`

Comment: 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland PRO [Radeon R7 240]
01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cape Verde/Pitcairn HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 7700/7800 Series]
02:00.0 USB controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. Device 3483 (rev 01)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
ls

Comment: description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 0c
       serial: fc:aa:14:7e:9f:63
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
      
      02/06/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe800fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff

Comment: driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-2_0.0.1 02/06/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:29 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:fe800000-fe800fff memory:d0000000-d0003fff

Comment: what does `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf | grep managed` gives you?

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal type:

`sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`

and change the line that says `managed=false` to `managed=true`

save the file and exit. Reboot your computer or just restart the network manager by:

`sudo service network-manager restart`

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks Ron, that's got the network connection working.  I still have a problem with a lot of apps but I think I know what the problem is. Sorry about the delay in replying but my windows has just done 197 updates and its taken about 4 hours

Comment: If my post answer your question mark it as the answer..